# Json Data Decoding without Library

Tags: json, parsing, decode

I don't want to use a library. I want to figure out how to parse JSON data properly myself.

Example content :

If I was to parse this :

```
{"Name": [
{
"Type": "Type1",
"Content": "Content 1"
}, 
{
"Type": "Type1",
"Content": "Content 2"
},
{
"Type": "Type2",
"Content": "Content 3"
},
{
"Type": "Type2",
"Content": "Content 4"
}
]
}
```

Would I simply go about using indices and substrings and so on?
Or is there something about String manipulation that I am missing out on?

Comment: Do you really want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Which language are we talking about? Javascript?

Comment: I'm gonna be using C# but the String manipulation functions on most languages are similar anyway so that doesn't matter.

Comment: Not really trying to reinvent, just wondering how it was done in the first place because the wheel I made is a bit clunky

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, eval() evaluates the expression. JSON is just a JS expression so it evaluates to an object. This is assuming the input is a valid JSON string. eval() runs all types of javascript code so beware of security.

Comment: Is there some way to get the code for the eval function? Or something similar?

Comment: @Democrats there is no additional code. Just take the JSON string and eval it.

    jsonstr = { "a": "firsmember", "b" : "secondmember"};
    jsonobj = eval(jsonstr);

Just a warning though, eval() does not do any validity or safety checking.